# How does Java derive the the Initialization vector from SecretKeySpec for AES?

Tags: java, aes

I'm trying to encrypt some text using AES on .net and have it read on Java.

The sample code I got for the encryption looks like this:

```
byte[] key = ...
SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
```

How does Java get the key and the IV from the SecretKey object? I need to provide them for .net and have found no information on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may provide the IV to the cipher in Java using an instance of [`IvParameterSpec`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/crypto/spec/IvParameterSpec.html) passed to [`Cipher.init`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html#init%28int,%20java.security.Key,%20java.security.spec.AlgorithmParameterSpec%29). If you don't, a random IV will be generated and made available by the [`getIV`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html#getIV%28%29) method of `Cipher`.

Comment: Understood. But if I don't, what does it use?

Comment: So, it's not derived from the key? Which would mean I'll be unable to decrypt if I don't take note of the generated value?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I just tried encrypting and decrypting using "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", and if I don't specify the IV before decrypting, I get "java.security.InvalidKeyException: Parameters missing". If you want it derived from the key, derive it yourself and initialize the cipher with the derived IV.

Comment: @Haas: It is not useful to derive the initialization vector from the key - you normally want to have a different initialization vector each time. (This is why an initialization vector is often passed along with a message.)

Comment: I truly agree @Paŭlo Ebermann, but it's the way the other end is doing it. I'm just complying.